# boost unordered_multimap loop over the unique keys

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

What is the easiest way to loop over the unique keys in a boost unordered_multimap.

For example I have this:

```
std::set<int> used;
for (auto p : valuesMap)
{
    if (used.count(p.first))
        continue;
    used.insert(p.first);

    auto range = valuesMap.equal_range(p.first);
    if (p.first)
    for (auto v = range.first; v != range.second; ++v)
        //do something;
}
```

Is there better way to do that. It seems like the unique keys should be already known to the unordered map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is find a way to get the iterator following a certain key. In `multimap` I'd usually use `upper_bound`. But since `unordered_multimap` doesn't have that - I'll have to use `equal_range.second`:

```
for (auto iter=valueMap.begin();
     iter!=valueMap.end();
     iter=ValueMap.equal_range(iter->first)->second){
  uniq_key=iter->first;
  // Do whatever you want with uniq_key
}
```

But your example is weird to me - because you DO go over all the element . If I wanted to write your code, doing what you do, this is how I'd do it:

```
for (auto iter=valueMap.begin()
     iter!=valueMap.end();
     ){ // Notice the lack of ++iter!!!
  auto end=valueMap.equal_range(ier->first)->second;
  for (;iter!=end;++iter)
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: the second thing seems like what I need. Let me test it and I will give you the check

Comment: yeap, I just replaced `for (;iter!=end;++iter) // Do something` with `do { // do somehting; } while (++iter != end);` to avoid one pointless check, but else it works.

Comment: i believe `ValueMap.equal_range(iter->first)->second` should be:
`ValueMap.equal_range(iter->first).second`

Comment: also @rabensky, if I wanted to use your top solution but get the LAST occurrence of the unique key instead of the first. How would I adjust the code?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom What is the distinction between "first" and "last" in an `unordered_multimap`? There's no guaranteed order...

But you could access the `equal_range(...).second` and then move it backwards once to get the "last" element. You'll need to tweek the loop to avoid calling `equal_range` twice though